# How can I ensure that the minimum version of Emacs used with some code is 28.2?

Tags: version-compatibilty

I'm using this.  What other ways are there?

```lisp
    (let ((minver "28.2"))
      (when (version< emacs-version minver)
        (error "This config requires Emacs v%s or higher." minver)))
    
    ;; Load the Emacs Lisp code blocks embedded in the literate Org file
    (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/custom-init.org"))
```

I want to do do the check in `init.el` before the literate configuration loads.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Not clear what the question is. Does your code do what you want? If not, specify the problem. if it does, then what are you asking for?

Comment: Yes, it does. I wasn't sure if "error" is the right function to use. My elisp knowledge is limited.

Comment: If your code works then what is the question? What are you requesting?

Comment: I think the question is something along "is it the correct/recomended way to do that?"